# Start service on other machine: service on Local Computer started and then stopped

Tags: c#, windows, service

I created a C# windows service and installed it successfully on my local developer machine (it works well).

Now I'm trying to install the service on a different machine.
I copied the "Release" folder to the new machine and installed the service.

When I start the service on the new machine I get the following error:
"service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."

I don't get any message to the Application event log, I even added debug message as the first line of the program, but i see nothing in the Event Viewer (as if the code doesn't start at all). :/

What have i done wrong?

Comment: Please post the code from your `OnStart` method.

Comment: I've removed the random link to what appears to be your website. Don't do that. Completely irrelevant to your post.

Comment: A common first-time-deployment-problem for Windows services pertains to the event log.  If your service writes to the application event log with a custom source, you need to create the source.  Normally an installer would do this for you.  Temporarily, try running the service under a privileged account like LocalSystem to see if your events show up.

Comment: Attached to the remote machine with your debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the problem:

I used password decryption with DataProctionScope.LocalMachine.
So when I changed the machine- the decryption failed.

I had to re-encrypt the passwords on the local machine and then the decryption worked fine.

Thank you for your responds!

*The eventlog debugging didn't work because of my fault.

Answer (score 0):

"started and then stopped" message usually appears when your server throws an exception during start up. Which could be for many reasons, including invalid paths and inability to write to the Application Event Log due to missing source or insufficient privileges.

I usually include an option to run my service as a console app.
Which allows me to display any exceptions using `Console.WriteLine`.

Following assumes your service extends from `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`.

```
partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyService svc = new MyService();

        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            RunConsole(args, svc);
        else
            Run(svc);
    }

    public MyService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected static bool KeepRunning { get; set; }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        StartServiceHost();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        StopServiceHost();
    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        StopServiceHost();
        base.OnShutdown();
    }

    private static void RunConsole(string[] args, ConverterService svc)
    {
        // need to hold on to Ctrl+C, otherwise StopServiceHost() never gets called
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) => ShutDown(svc);

        KeepRunning = true;

        svc.OnStart(args);
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Ctrl+C> to exit.");
        while (KeepRunning)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private void StartServiceHost()
    {
        // start your service
    }

    private void StopServiceHost()
    {
        // stop your service
    }

    private static void ShutDown(MyService svc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exiting...");
        svc.OnStop();
        KeepRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution for debugging in the developer machine, however my problem was in other machine- so the proper way to debug was to write to the Applicaiton event log.